# Truncate a Duration in Java

Tags: java, truncate, duration, truncation

When capturing elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), I only care about whole seconds resolution.

How do I drop the fractional second from a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object?

Other classes in the *java.time* framework offer a `truncatedTo` method. But I do not see one on [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Java 9 and later

[Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and bug fixes to the *java.time* classes that debuted in Java 8.

One of those features is adding a [`Duration::truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method, similar to such methods seen on other classes. Pass a [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) (an implementation of [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) interface) to specify the granularity of what to truncate.

```
Duration d = myDuration.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

## Java 8

If you are using [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and cannot yet move to Java 9, 10, 11, or later, then calculate the truncation yourself.

Call the [`minusNanos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#minusNanos-long-) method found on the Java 8 version of [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Get the number of nanoseconds on the `Duration` object, then subtract that number of nanoseconds.

```
Duration d = myDuration.minusNanos( myDuration.getNano() ) ;
```

The *java.time* classes use the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern. So you get back a fresh new object without altering (“mutating”) the original.

Answer (score 2):

I like [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50031958/5772882). I know this was not what you asked, yet I’d like to present one or two options for Java 8 for the cases where we want to truncate to a unit other than seconds.

If we know the unit at the time we are writing the code, we may combine the `toXx` and the `ofXx` methods to form the truncated duration:

```
    Duration d = Duration.ofMillis(myDuration.toMillis());
    Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(myDuration.toSeconds());
    Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes(myDuration.toMinutes());
    Duration d = Duration.ofHours(myDuration.toHours());
    Duration d = Duration.ofDays(myDuration.toDays());
```

If the unit is variable, we may adapt the code from the implementation of the Java 9 method you mentioned, `truncatedTo`:

```
    Duration d;
    if (unit.equals(ChronoUnit.SECONDS) 
            && (myDuration.getSeconds() >= 0 || myDuration.getNano() == 0)) {
        d = Duration.ofSeconds(myDuration.getSeconds());
    } else if (unit == ChronoUnit.NANOS) {
        d = myDuration;
    }
    Duration unitDur = unit.getDuration();
    if (unitDur.getSeconds() > TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1)) {
        throw new UnsupportedTemporalTypeException("Unit is too large to be used for truncation");
    }
    long dur = unitDur.toNanos();
    if ((TimeUnit.DAYS.toNanos(1) % dur) != 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedTemporalTypeException("Unit must divide into a standard day without remainder");
    }
    long nod = (myDuration.getSeconds() % TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1)) * TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1)
            + myDuration.getNano();
    long result = (nod / dur) * dur;
    d = myDuration.plusNanos(result - nod);
```

The original method used some private stuff from the `Duration` class, so a number of changes were necessary. The code only accepts `ChronoUnit` units, not other `TemporalUnit`s. I haven’t considered how hard it would be to generalize it.