# How can I truncate a Kotlin Duration?

Tags: kotlin

Java's Duration has [a truncate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50031958/4161471).

```java
Duration d = myDuration.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

> [`public Duration truncatedTo​(TemporalUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)
>
> Returns a copy of this Duration truncated to the specified unit.
>
> Truncating the duration returns a copy of the original with conceptual fields smaller than the specified unit set to zero. For example, truncating with the `MINUTES` unit will round down to the nearest minute, setting the seconds and nanoseconds to zero.

However Kotlin has [a different implementation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/#duration) for Duration, and this does not have an analogous truncation method.

I want to be able to divide or multiply a Duration by some number, and then (with an extension function) remove any time unit smaller than the one I supply.

```kotlin
import kotlin.time.*
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.days
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.hours
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.minutes


fun main() {
   val duration = 10.days + 5.hours + 33.minutes
   println(duration)

   val divided = duration / 100.001
   println(divided)

   val truncatedToSeconds = divided.truncate(DurationUnit.SECONDS)
   println(truncatedToSeconds) // expect: 2h 27m 19s
   
   val truncatedToMinutes = divided.truncate(DurationUnit.MINUTES)
   println(truncatedToMinutes) // expect: 2h 27m

   val truncatedToHours = divided.truncate(DurationUnit.HOURS)
   println(truncatedToHours) // expect: 2h
}

fun Duration.truncate(unit: DurationUnit): Duration {
   /// ...
   return this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure-Kotlin truncation function.

It uses [`Duration.toComponents()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/to-components.html) to get the constituent components of the duration. It then converts each back into a `Duration`, depending on whether it is equal to or larger than the requested `DurationUnit`.

```kotlin
import kotlin.time.*
import kotlin.time.DurationUnit.*
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.days
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.hours
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.minutes
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.milliseconds
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.microseconds
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.nanoseconds
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

/**
 * Truncates the duration to the specified [unit].
 *
 * Truncating the duration removes any time units smaller than the specified unit
 * and returns a new [Duration] with the truncated value.
 *
 * @param unit The duration unit to truncate to.
 * @returns a new [Duration] truncated to the specified [unit].
 */
private fun Duration.truncate(unit: DurationUnit): Duration {
  return toComponents { days: Long, hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int, nanoseconds: Int ->
    when (unit) {
      NANOSECONDS  -> this // there's no smaller unit than NANOSECONDS, so just return the current Duration
      MICROSECONDS -> days.days + hours.hours + minutes.minutes + seconds.seconds + nanoseconds.nanoseconds.inWholeMicroseconds.microseconds
      MILLISECONDS -> days.days + hours.hours + minutes.minutes + seconds.seconds + nanoseconds.nanoseconds.inWholeMilliseconds.milliseconds
      SECONDS      -> days.days + hours.hours + minutes.minutes + seconds.seconds
      MINUTES      -> days.days + hours.hours + minutes.minutes
      HOURS        -> days.days + hours.hours
      DAYS         -> days.days
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:

- `nanoseconds` [is documented as being less than `1_000_000_000`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/to-components.html) (1 second), so there's no need to convert it to seconds.
- In order to round the nanoseconds to microseconds the `nanoseconds` value is first converted to a duration (`nanoseconds.nanoseconds`), then rounded to microseconds (`inWholeMicroseconds`) and then converted to a duration (`.microseconds`). The same process is used to round nanoseconds to milliseconds.

#### Example

Here's an example usage demonstrates the `truncate()` function applied to a duration using different time units. Each truncation removes all time units smaller than the specified unit.

```kotlin
import kotlin.time.*
import kotlin.time.DurationUnit.*
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.days
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.hours
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.minutes
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.milliseconds
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.microseconds
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.nanoseconds
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

fun main() {
  // create a duration
  val duration = 1.hours + 30.minutes + 45.seconds + 2.milliseconds + 3.microseconds + 5.nanoseconds
  println(duration)                        // 1h 30m 45.002003005s
  println(duration.truncate(NANOSECONDS))  // 1h 30m 45.002003005s (no truncation - can't go smaller than the smallest unit)
  println(duration.truncate(MICROSECONDS)) // 1h 30m 45.002003s    (no nanoseconds)
  println(duration.truncate(MILLISECONDS)) // 1h 30m 45.002s       (no milliseconds or nanoseconds)
  println(duration.truncate(SECONDS))      // 1h 30m 45s     (milliseconds and smaller are truncated)
  println(duration.truncate(MINUTES))      // 1h 30m         (seconds and smaller are truncated)
  println(duration.truncate(HOURS))        // 1h             (minutes and smaller are truncated)
  println(duration.truncate(DAYS))         // 0s             (all units are zeroed)
}
```

```
1h 30m 45.002003005s
1h 30m 45.002003005s
1h 30m 45.002003s
1h 30m 45.002s
1h 30m 45s
1h 30m
1h
0s
```

[*Run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/Xlnx0Ghmm)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to convert it to a `Long` and back again, using your desired unit:

```kotlin
fun Duration.truncate(unit: DurationUnit): Duration =
    toLong(unit).toDuration(unit)
```