# Formatting kotlin time Duration

Tags: kotlin, time, duration

Is there any convenient way to format kotlin.time.Duration to string as I can do with LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormatter?

For example:

```
val time = LocalDateTime.now()
d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss")
```

I know about Duration's absoluteValue, but it doesn't round values, i.e. I got durations like

```
3m 19.1666666666s
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit:
What I have tried:

```
val x = 333.333333333333.toDuration(DurationUnit.SECONDS)

println(z.absoluteValue) //55m 33.33333333s
println(z.inWholeSeconds) //3333
println(z.inWholeMinutes) //55
println(z.toString(DurationUnit.MINUTES, 2) // 55,56m
```

What I've found and closest to what I need:
[How can I truncate a Kotlin Duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985870/how-can-i-truncate-a-kotlin-duration)

Comment: Neither knowing Kotlin nor kotlin.time, I think I’d try the `toComponents` method to get days, hours, minutes and seconds separately and then format them (or the relevant ones) into a string to my liking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `inWhole*` properties of the `Duration` class. So in your example, a duration of 3m19.1666s would be `duration.inWholeSeconds` -> 3m19s or `duration.inWholeMinutes` -> 3m.

If you want to make use of Duration's toString, simply convert back to a Duration: `duration.inWholeSeconds.seconds.toString()` -> prints 3m19s

Comment: Thank you, but I think inWhole* is not exactly what I need. I've edited my question.

Comment: @user2424380 Why is it not what you need? This allows you to truncate to a time unit, and that's all you've asked for. The printing after that is trivial. Right?